# wordpress : Authors not able to submit content

Tags: php, wordpress, submit, author

I have a wordpress installation and have different hierarchies of users to publish content. My wordpress version is 2.9 and I am stuck with an issue that is different authors(lowest level in the hierarchy) are not able to publish content.

When ever they hit publish button, the page refreshes and it gets stuck on post.php with nothing to display in the browser window, if the author goes back and publish again, the content is published.

Also this problem is intermittent and some times it runs very smoothly and some times refreshing the page 5-6 times does the trick and all the content is published.

Every thing was normal but an security update happened automatically and above mentioned issue started occuring.

To solve the issue I created a staging installation (exact copy of live server). After that I deactivated/uninstalled all the plugins and upgraded to wordpress 4.0 , still the issue is not solved but for the time being, authors able to publish the content in one go without any media (only text as the add media button stopped working).

But it lead to a new error that a file object-cache.php had some dependent files that were missing, so I deleted the w3-object-cache folder from the plugins directory.

it solved the object cache missing support files problem. But While testing, the add media button stopped working and i am not able to add media from the library to the posts.

I have no idea how to move forward.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do one thing..Deactivate all your plugin and then see if Add Media button is working or not .

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner  applying this and will get back in 30 mins

Comment: @Fresher applying this and will get back in 30 mins